# Typescript azure function tablestorage binding giving 500

Tags: typescript, azure-functions

For my typescript function I was trying out accessing tablestorage. (consumption function, Linux, node runtime)

```
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions"

const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest): Promise<void> {
    context.log('HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    const name = (req.query.name || (req.body && req.body.name));
    var responseMessage = name
        ? "Hello, " + name + ". This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
        : "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.";

context.bindings.tableBinding = []; 
 context.bindings.tableBinding.push({
        PartitionKey: "Test",
        RowKey: "iii",
        Name: "Name "
    });

    context.res = {
        // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
        body: responseMessage
    };

};

export default httpTrigger;
```

Binding in function.json

```
    {
      "tableName": "GameState",
      "connection": "",
      "name": "tableBinding",
      "type": "table",
      "direction": "out"
    },
```

However as response I get an internal server error 500.

With the baffling error

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.writeToTable '' is not a valid value for a partition key or row key.
```

Any thoughts on how to fiz/debug this further?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using version 3.0, this might have caused the error for the Table Storage bindings. Try changing the version to 2.0.

Extension bundle example in version 2.0

```
 {
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensionBundle": {
        "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
        "version": "[3.3.0, 4.0.0)"
    }
 }
```

References:

- [Register Azure Functions binding extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-register)

Comment: I was using 2.0. However, I was also using the preview extensionbundle, maybe that didn't help:
"Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle.Preview"

Either way I switched to the tableClient SDK. This entire experience really did turn me off from using bindings.